# Software recommendations for passivating structures

Tags: reference-request, software-recommendations, quantum-atk

I am looking for an open-source library that allows to passivate a structure, ideally starting from a xyz-file.

QuantumATK provides a function like this. However, this is not an option at the moment.

If there is no such software, how do you create passivated structures?

Edit: To clarify what I mean when I say "passivate": I mean just adding e.g. H atoms to the dangling bonds.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by passivate the structure?  Just terminate with H+ or OH- etc?

Comment: @TristanMaxson Yes, exactly.

Comment: Are there language restrictions (e.g. you don't want to work with FORTRAN, etc.)? There are a few exhaustive lists already though they aren't exactly searchable re: support for passivity, e.g. https://opensourcemolecularmodeling.github.io/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid-state_physics_software, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_for_nanostructures_modeling. Heck, https://nanohub.org/ might even be useful.

Comment: @TylerH No there are no language restrictions. I am open to working with any program that is open source and solves the problem.

Comment: @random01 Does it need to be "open-source" or just "free" ? Is a program that's free but with invisible source, okay? I still don't know any software that does this, but the answer to this might help in case someone else were to avoid answering just because their suggestion is not open-source.

Comment: @TylerH bounty expires in 18 hours

Comment: @CodyAldaz I did see that it expires in the next day or so; I don't have any *specific* libraries or tools in mind (and I don't think pure links to entire lists of options is appropriate/worth posting as an answer, especially when attempting to vie for a bounty).

Comment: @TylerH an answer should have one topic. It's a little different but we've had a lot of success with this type of format, see https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/52

Comment: @CodyAldaz I agree with that statement, but I'm not sure how it applies to my comment? I shared the links as a comment, because the links each jump back to *rather long* lists, none of which I have checked for: open source, support for .xyz file format, and perhaps most importantly support for passivating molecular structures. And a link to a page that (potentially) has an answer is a [signpost saying 'your answer is in another castle'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). It's not an answer itself :-)

Comment: @TylerH ahh I misread your comment. Too bad the bounty is going to waste tho!

Comment: @NikeDattani: Open-source would be better, but free is okay as well.

Answer (score 7):

There are actually quite a number of tools that can be used to passivate a structure. They all work differently, and none are perfect at what they do. If you're dealing with organic molecules, these codes will work far better than if you're dealing with inorganic complexes.

Here is a list of some tools you may be interested in:

- [PyMOL](https://pymol.org/2/) has an [H Add](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/H_Add) function. PyMOL accepts many kinds of formats. Commercial software with a free academic license.
- [Avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/) has an option for automatically adding H atoms to a structure, as described [here](https://avogadro.cc/docs/menus/build-menu/). Free and open-source.
- [Olex](https://www.olexsys.org/) has a similar command as PyMOL called `hadd`, as described [here](http://crystals.otterbein.edu/teaching/docs/olex2_quick_ref.pdf). This program is widely used when dealing with CIFs. Free software.
- [Reduce](http://kinemage.biochem.duke.edu/software/reduce.php), [Chimera](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/ContributedSoftware/addh/addh.html), and [MOPAC](http://openmopac.net/manual/Adding_Hydrogen_atoms.html) can all be used to automatically add H atoms to PDB structures. Free software (for non-commercial users).
- [Quantum ATK](https://www.synopsys.com/silicon/quantumatk.html) has a [passivate option](https://docs.quantumatk.com/tutorials/builder_manual/builder_plugins/builder_plugins.html). Commercial software.
- [CrystalMaker](http://crystalmaker.com/) has an option for automatically adding H atoms in its Molecule Builder utility, as listed [here](http://crystalmaker.com/crystalmaker/specs/index.html). Commercial software.
- [Materials Studio](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/biovia/products/molecular-modeling-simulation/biovia-materials-studio/) has an option for automatically adding H atoms. Commercial software.

There are likely many, many others.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at the free software from the list. Commercial software is not an option at the moment as stated in the question.

Comment: There was some discussion [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6897/tool-to-saturate-the-dangling-bonds-at-the-surface-of-nanostructures) of merging these two questions. I think the other question is formulated a little more clearly so I considering having that one as the master question. Do you have any objection to this? The OP hasn't been on the site in several months, so I'll take your opinion as the deciding factor on whether to merge them or leave them alone.